# parsing an xml type string

Tags: c#, silverlight, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

I have a string like this

```xml
<InitParams>
                <myparams>

                  <Ad>true</Ad>
                  <Ay>true</Ay>
                  <Sd>false</Sd>

                </myparams>
                <myContent>

                  <Item>
                      <IM>true</IM>
                      <AL>1234</AL>

                    </Item>

                </myContent>
              </InitParams>
```

I need the value between the tags `<IM>` and `<AL>`. Being new to C# and .net not sure what would be the best way to do it. Read up on xmlDoc and linq but sounds like overkill for this small need.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using an XML API to process XML. In fact, that's the right way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of something like LINQ to XML was to prevent overkill, because it's so easy to use:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Xml.Linq;



 namespace WhateverNamespaceYouWant
 {

    public class Item
    {
        public bool IM { get; set; }
        public int AL { get; set; }
    }
    public class ItemsRepository
    {
        public IEnumerable<Item> GetAllItemsInXML()
        {
            var _items = new List<Item>();
            var doc = XDocument.Load("this");
            // finds every node of Item
            doc.Descendants("Item").ToList()
            .ForEach(item =>
            {
                var myItem = new Item() // your domain type
                {
                    IM = item.Element("IM").Value.ConvertToValueType<bool>(),
                    AL = item.Element("AL").Value.ConvertToValueType<int>(),
                };
                _items.Add(myItem);
            });
            return _items;
        }
    }

    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static T ConvertToValueType<T>(this string str) where T : struct
        {
            try
            {
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(str, typeof(T));
            }
            catch
            {
                return default(T);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I never saw you could do `Value.ConvertToValueType` i always wrap value with a `Convert.To...`

Comment: ConvertToValueType<T> is one of my extension methods I use regularly.

Comment: Oh I see, I have a Surround snippet for `Convert.to...`

Comment: It will try to convert to that type (has to be a Value type) or give you back the default for that type if it fails.

Comment: it highlights these in red, saying I am missing a namespace, List<Item>(); XDocument., xmlToParse, new Item();

Comment: @Autolycus replace that with `Convert.ToTYPE(item.Element("IM").Value)`

Comment: you can ignore the IRepository<Item>, that's just a suggestion on how to frame your repository, base it off an IRepository<T> T being your Domain type that would map what is in the XML.

Comment: I couldnt get it to work...it gives me directive missing for Items

Comment: yeah you need to create the class (domain object) called Items.  I'll add it to the code above.

Comment: this parts still have issues
  IM = item.Element("IM").Value.ConvertToValueType<bool>(),
              AL = item.Element("AL").Value.ConvertToValueType<int>(),

Comment: also this  return (T)Convert.ChangeType(str, typeof(T));

Comment: ok, I wrote all of that by hand in the text editor so there were going to be mistakes, thought you would get the gist.  I put it in VS and resolved everything so it compiles.  Notice you'll have to put in your XML string (or file path) where I say "this"

Comment: No it still has the same issue as I described above

Comment: that part had an issue because I put a semicolon after Item(), copy and paste everything you see in the text into a new file including the using statements.  If there is an error it might be because one of the using statement's libraries isn't in your project.  Also this is in VS2010 using C# 4.

Comment: ok I see whats going on...when I use it in a separate file, it gives no errors but when I include it in my already class, it gives errors. Somehow I was just looking for a method not a class. How would I call this class from my current class and pass the string to it?

Comment: didnt work, but giving you credit for your help. I am gonna go another route

Comment: you new up this class inside that class, var itemsRepo = new ItemsRepository();  Then use that instance, var items = itemsRepo.GetAllItemsInXML();